# Clamp rotation problems in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to limit my rotation of x axis but it does not clamp at all. It is like there is no effect. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float minRotation = -45;
    public float maxRotation = 10;

    void Update()
    {
       
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
   
           float xaxisRotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed;
           xaxisRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xaxisRotation, minRotation, maxRotation);
           transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, xaxisRotation);
  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please refere https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve the question accordingly

Answer (score -1):

You clamp the max rotation that is applied every frame.
So if you want to clamp the rotation itself you would have to clamp the total rotation.

Try:

```
public float speed = 5f;
public float minRotation = -45;
public float maxRotation = 10;

void Update()
{
   
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {

       float xaxisRotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed;
       transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, xaxisRotation);
       transform.y = Mathf.Clamp(transform.eulerAngles.y, minRotation, maxRotation);

    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error ```Transform does not contain a definition for 'y'```

Comment: Sorry transform.position.y